# Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with $\gcd(|G|,3)=1$. Show that $G=\{x^3:x\in G\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, alternative-proof

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with $\gcd(|G|,3)=1$. If $\theta:G\longrightarrow G$, $x\longmapsto x^3$ is a homomorphism of groups, we want to prove that $$G=\{x^3:x\in G\}.$$

To this end, we claim that $\ker \theta =1$. Indeed, if $a\in \ker \theta$, then $g^3=1_G$. So $|g| \mid 3$. On the other hand, $|g|\mid |G|$. So, $|g|\mid \gcd(|G|,3)$ and therefore $g=1_G$.
Hence $\theta$ is injective which maps the finite group $G$ into itself. Therefore, $\theta$ is surjective (and hence $\theta\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$). Then,
$$G=\mathrm{im}\theta=\{x^3:x\in G\}$$
and the result follows.

> My question is whether we could work as follows: Take an $g\in G$. Then, using Bezout's identity,
> $$g=g^1=g^{|G|a+3b}=(g^b)^3\in \mathrm{im}(\theta)$$
> where $a,b$ are integers and $g^b\in G$. So, could we omit using that way the whole premise about the homomorphism $\theta$?

Thanks.

Update: Many apologies, I forgot to define $\theta$!

Comment: It looks fine to me...

Comment: Thanks! So the given homomorphism seems to be unnecessary!

Comment: I understand that $\theta$ is the map that sends each $g$ to $g^3$, but maybe you should state that explicitly when you first introduce the notation $\theta$. Now it initially looks like a random homomorphism

Comment: I am less positive than the answerers/other commenters here. For example, $\theta$ is never defined, so both proofs make no sense. It would make more sense if you defined $\theta$ to be $\theta(x)=x^3$, or said "Prove that $G=\{x^3 : x\in G\}$. To do this, let $\theta: G\rightarrow G$ be a homomorphism...". But it doesn't say this...

Comment: Wait, I think I understand (but then your question isn't clear!): The first proof uses the assumption that $\theta: x\mapsto x^3$ is a homomorphism (specifically, it uses kernels). Your proof considers the same map, but does *not* assume it is a homomorphism. Is this what you're getting at? (If so, this is fine, but rewrite your question so this is clearer.)

Comment: Dear @1729, thank you for getting this point! I forgot to define $\theta$ -- many apologies for that! If you wish, restate your answers :)

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for getting that point, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, you say *if* $\theta$ is a homomorphism, then ... You need the group to be abelian in order for $\theta$ in fact to be a homomorphism. Rewrite necessary.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the comment, Professor. Well, it's not difficult to prove that  if $\theta$ is a homomorphism then $G$ is abelian and vice versa. The premise here was that $\theta:x\mapsto x^3$ *is* a homomorphism and I was wondering if that premise was unecessary, using Bezout.

Comment: It could have been clearer, but I see your intent.

Answer (score 3):

The first proof uses the fact that $\theta$ is a homomorphism, as it proves that $\ker\theta=1$. This means that $\theta$ is injective, and so bijective as the groups are finite.

Your proof is correct, and does not use the fact that $\theta$ is a homomorphism. It is therefore a *better* proof. Which is nice.

---

Both proofs use the fact that the groups are finite, as you prove surjectivity (rather than injectivity) of $\theta$, and then use the fact that $G$ is finite to get that it is a bijection.

**Question.** Can we push this proof to work for infinite groups?

Yes, we can! A group $G$ is called *torsion* if every element has finite order. For $h\in G$, I will write $\langle h\rangle:=\{h^i\mid i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for *subgroup generated by $h$*.

**Lemma.** If $G$ is a torsion group with no element of order divisible by $3$, then the map $\theta: x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection.

*Proof.*
Lets use your proof as a starting point, but with a necessary, minor tweak:
Take any $g\in G$. Then, using Bezout's identity,
$$g=g^1=g^{o(g)a+3b}=(g^b)^3\in \operatorname{im}(\theta)$$
where $o(g)$ denotes the order of $g\in G$, $a,b$ are integers and $g^b\in G$.
Hence, $\theta$ is surjective.

To see that $\theta$ is injective, suppose that $\theta(g)=\theta(h)$, that is $g^3=h^3$, and we'll prove that $g=h$. As $g=(g^b)^3$ we have:
$$g=(g^b)^3=(g^3)^b=(h^3)^b.$$
This means that $g\in \langle h\rangle$. Now, the restriction of $\theta$ to $\langle h\rangle$ has image contained in $\langle h\rangle$, and as $\langle h\rangle$ is finite this is the setting of the original question. Hence, the restricted map $\theta|_{\langle h\rangle}: \langle h\rangle\rightarrow \langle h\rangle$ is a bijection. As $g, h\in\langle h \rangle$, it follows that $g=h$ as required.

Comment: Nice answer and extension of my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The map $\theta_i:x\mapsto x^i$ for $i>1$ is not in general a homomorphism for finite groups $G$. It *is* a homomorphism whenever a group $G$ is abelian, though, as is easy to see.

Thus we cannot use the fact that $\theta$ is a homomorphism, since it isn't!

It is a homomorphism on the subgroup $X=\langle x\rangle$ though. And if $|X|$ is prime to $i$, then $\theta_i$ must be injective, since no element of $X$ can be mapped to $1$ (other than $1$) as $|X|$ can contain no elements of order $i$ by Langrage's theorem. Injective maps from a finite set to itself are bijective, and so there are (unique) $i$th roots of any given element.

Since every element has an $i$th root if $\gcd(|G|,i)=1$, the map (not homomorphism) $\theta_i:G\to G$ is bijective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can omit those details.

---

Here's another proof (without even using $\theta$) . . .

To show $H\le G$, since $G$ is finite and $e\in H:=\{ x^3\mid x\in G\}$, [it suffices to show that $H$ is closed under $G$'s operation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test).

Let $h,k\in H$. Then $h,k\in G$ so, by Bézout's Theorem and $\gcd(|G|,3)=1$, we have some $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ such that $|G|a+3b=1$; now

$$\begin{align}
hk&=(hk)^1\\
&=(hk)^{|G|a+3b}\\
&=((hk)^b)^3\\
&\in H \quad \text{(since }(hk)^b\in G\text{)},
\end{align}$$

which is what we wanted to show.

---

In fact, $H\subseteq G$ by definition.

---

But, as you have observed, for any $g\in G$, we have some $c\in\Bbb Z$ such that $g=(g^c)^3\in H$. Hence $G\subseteq H$.

---

Hence $G\cong H$; indeed, we can say $G=H$.

Comment: So instead of directly showing that $G \subseteq H$ you use exactly the same method to show the weaker statement $H \cdot H \subseteq H$ and then use a fancy fact that this is enough? This hardly makes sense to me.

Comment: No, @Adayah; $H$ is finite because $G$ is, so, as I have said, since $H$ is nonempty, it suffices to show $H$ is closed under $G$'s multiplication to show $H\le G$.

Comment: I know. I'm not saying your argument is incorrect (which it isn't), I'm only saying that your proof is basically the same as OP's yet needlessly more complicated.

Comment: I agree with that, actually, @Adayah. I was half asleep when I typed this answer. Shall I delete it?

Comment: It's up to you.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the answer, please have a look at my update. Hope you slept well yesterday (joking) :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Chris. Thank you. I have updated my answer.